# Is there an way to extract data from an xml section in a json object using snowflake

Tags: sql, xml, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a Json object in snowflake and the Json object has a XML element. I am trying to extract some data from it but it seems to be returning a null

```
CREATE TABLE sample_xml(id INT, json_data VARIANT);

INSERT INTO sample_xml(id, json_data)
select  2, parse_json($$
  {
"typ": "info",
  "hostname": "lee007",
  "platform": "lee007",
  "side": "b",
  "requestObject": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><s:Body xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><OrderReshopRQ Version=\"17.2\" xmlns=\"http://www.iata.org/IATA/EDIST/2017.2\"><Document><Name>BA</Name></Document><Party><Sender><TravelAgencySender><IATA_Number>33895934</IATA_Number><AgencyID>FAREPORTAL</AgencyID></TravelAgencySender></Sender><Participants xsi:nil=\"true\"/><Recipient xsi:nil=\"true\"/></Party><Query><OrderID>TUHVO8</OrderID><Reshop><OrderServicing><Delete><OrderItem OrderItemID=\"TUHVO8\"/></Delete></OrderServicing></Reshop></Query></OrderReshopRQ></s:Body></s:Envelope>",
  "ip": "192.000.000.0",
  "level": "INFO",
  "sheryname": "taltech"
}
$$);
 
WITH xml as (
select id,
TO_OBJECT(PARSE_XML(json_data:requestObject)) as XML_data
from sample_xml 
)
select ID,
        xmlget(XML_data, 'IATA_Number') : "$" :: string
from xml
```

the Parsed XML looks like this

```
    <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <OrderReshopRQ xmlns="http://www.iata.org/IATA/EDIST/2017.2" Version="17.2">
      <Document>
        <Name>opA</Name>
      </Document>
      <Party>
        <Sender>
          <TravelAgencySender>
            <IATA_Number>33898734</IATA_Number>
            <AgencyID>FAREPORTAL</AgencyID>
          </TravelAgencySender>
        </Sender>
        <Participants xsi:nil="true"/>
        <Recipient xsi:nil="true"/>
      </Party>
      <Query>
        <OrderID>TUHVO8</OrderID>
        <Reshop>
          <OrderServicing>
            <Delete>
              <OrderItem OrderItemID="TUHVO8"/>
            </Delete>
          </OrderServicing>
        </Reshop>
      </Query>
    </OrderReshopRQ>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The objective is to extract the IATA_Number. When I try to using the code above I get nulls when trying to extract IATA_Number(for example) from the xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I find) dealing with XML is a bit painful but basically you need to traverse down through the hierarchy to get to the level where the attribute is that you want. Not covered below but if you have repeating elements then you have to start using LATERAL FLATTEN clauses as well.

In this SQL, I've created a column for each level of the hierarchy and then referenced its alias in the next column - just to try and make it easier to read. Obviously you could nest all the XMLGETs in a single statement.

```
with cte1 as (
select PARSE_XML(json_data:requestObject)::variant as XML1
from sample_xml 
)
select 
*
,xmlget(xml1,'s:Body') L1
,XMLGET(L1, 'OrderReshopRQ') L2
,XMLGET(L2, 'Party') L3
,XMLGET(L3,'Sender') L4
,XMLGET(L4,'TravelAgencySender') L5
,XMLGET(L5,'IATA_Number'):"$" IATA_Number
from cte1
;
```